# Where does Scala's 'NotInferedT' come from?

Tags: scala

In Scala, we can get a compile error with a message containing 'NotInferedT'. For example :

```
 expected: (NotInferedT, NotInferedT) => Boolean, actual: (Nothing, Nothing)
```

(as seen [here](https://github.com/danielmiladinov/scala-programming-learnings/blob/master/examples/merge_sort.scala) ).

This messge is coming from the Scala compiler, and it appears to mean that Scala cannot infer a type. But is 'NotInferedT' itself a type ? And is it described in the Scala documentation somewhere ?
I can't find 'NotInferedT' in the [Scala API docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/) .

Comment: I think 'NotiInferedT' is just a nickname for a type Scala could not infer (deduce from the rest of code)

Comment: @ilmirons: If its just a nickname and no such type exists, then its quite a strange nickname. I wonder why they compiler writers picked that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It's the way the Scala plugin (which is basically a Scala compiler) for IntelliJ IDEA names an undefined type it can't resolve:](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-scala/blob/cb982abc94dcbd9897a1aeadd58f0f49eec500bb/scala/scala-impl/src/org/jetbrains/plugins/scala/lang/psi/types/ScalaTypePresentation.scala#L245)

```
case UndefinedType(tpt, _) => "NotInfered" + tpt.name
```